# Как сделать определенный вид даты?

Tags: дата, php, время

подскажите как сделать такой вид даты? 
n - день - n месяца год время (часы:минуты)
пример: 12 января 2014 19:25

нужно для регистрации пользователя.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не обязательно выводить именно русское название месяца:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
echo date("d F Y H:i");
//07 February 2014 16:10
```

Если обязательно:

```
$m = array("Января",   "Февраля", "Марта",  "Апреля",
           "Мая",      "Июня",    "Июля",   "Августа",
           "Сентября", "Октября", "Ноября", "Декабря");

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
echo date("d ") . $m[(int) date('n') - 1] . date(" Y H:i");
//07 Февраля 2014 16:15
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// забирает текущее время в массив
$timestamp = time();
$date_time_array = getdate($timestamp);

$hours = $date_time_array['hours'];
$minutes = $date_time_array['minutes'];
$seconds = $date_time_array['seconds'];
$month = $date_time_array['mon'];
$day = $date_time_array['mday'];
$year = $date_time_array['year'];

// используйте mktime для обновления UNIX времени
$timestamp = mktime($hours,$minutes,$seconds,$month,$day,$year);
$rusmonth = strftime('%B',$timestamp);
$trans = array("January" => "января",
               "February" => "февраля",
               "March" => "марта",
               "April" => "апреля",
           "May" => "мая",
               "June" => "июня",
               "July" => "июля",
               "August" => "августа",
               "September" => "сентября",
               "October" => "октября",
               "November" => "ноября",
               "December" => "декабря"
               );
$rusmonth = strtr($rusmonth, $trans);
echo ' '; 
echo $rusmonth;
echo ' ';
echo strftime('%Y',$timestamp);
echo ' ';
echo strftime('%e',$timestamp);
```